# Pass additional parameters to karate-config.js via command line via Maven

Tags: karate

I have additional settings that I need to pass to Karate when running via Maven that will be available in karate-config.js. Currently I can pass in a string using the karate.env property - is it necessary to encode my parameters as a JSON object and pass them in via this one property or can I do something like:

```
mvn test -DargLine="-Dkarate.env='production' -Dkarate.clientid='1234567890' ...
```

Such that I can then reference karate.clientid in karate-config.js where I can save it into the returned config object.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here...

Comment: I found I can do `mvn test -D karate.clientId=123 -D karate.baseurl=test.com` without the -DargLine

Comment: @Dunk could you explain more please about what exactly you did for your case. We can't change karate-config.js variables from command line. Example: clientId, baseUrl.. Thanks

Comment: Peter answer looks good and is there an alternate way like give the parameters from Jenkins and retrieve it in karate config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes ! Refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate#the-karate-object) for `karate.properties['karate.clientid']`.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the parameters like this

```
mvn test -D clientId=123 -D baseurl=test.com
```

and refer them in the karate-config.js as

```
karate.properties['clientId'] and karate.properties['baseurl']
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way, but I didn't use examples. What I've done:

- In Gradle:

  ```
  task api(type:Test) {
     systemProperty "karate.clientId", System.properties.getProperty("karate.clientId")...
   }
  ```
- In `karate-config.js` (in `var config`):

  ```
  clientId: karate.properties['karate.clientId'] || 'xyz'
  ```
- In the command line:

  ```
  '-Dkarate.clientId=abc'
  ```

If I don't set the `clientId` in my command line, the `clientId` will be `'xyz'`.