# I want to pass multiple arguments in karate-config.js through mvn command

Tags: karate

I want to want pass multiple arguments in mvn command and and that should be read in karate-config.js file.

```
e.g: mvn test -DargLine="-Dkarate.env='gdcStaging', -Dkarate.source='false', -Dkarate.natco='gdc'"
```

I didn't want to declare any .prop files, want to get these values at run time.
Below prop. are defined to read these arguments but unable to achieve from this:

```
var environment = karate.env;
var natco = karate.properties['karate.natco'];
var isLocal = java.lang.System.getenv('karate.source');
```

I need help to achieve this

> karate-version=0.9.0

I had also referred to this link :[Pass additional parameters to karate-config.js via command line via Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671916/pass-additional-parameters-to-karate-config-js-via-command-line-via-maven)
but not worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `argLine` try passing it directly,

```
mvn test -Dkarate.env=gdcStaging -Dkarate.source=false -Dkarate.natco=gdc
```

> I suggest not to use `karate.` as a prefix to your arguments other
>   than `karate.env`, instead try using your application name.
>   eg,

```
-Dmyapp.source=false
```

coming to the karate-config.js

```
var natco = karate.properties['myapp.source']
```

This should work.