# karate argLine arguments not picked up with 'mvn gatling:test' command

Tags: karate

I have an existing suite of karate tests which can run on different environments (dev / qa) using the approach below:

```
mvn test -DargLine="-DauthUser=*** -DauthPassword=*** -Dkarate.env=qa"
```

Now i have added some gatling tests and when try to run the tests on 'qa' with the following command, the tests still run on my default environment which is 'dev' instead of 'qa'.

```
mvn gatling:test -DargLine="-DauthUser=*** -DauthPassword=*** -Dkarate.env=qa"
```

Seems like the argLine approach will not work with maven gatling plugin. If not, is there any other way of passing these arguments for gatling tests?

Comment: am not clear, maybe to help others, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - also try using os env: `java.lang.System.getenv('PATH')`

Comment: @PeterThomas eg., when i run the karate tests, i can see that the env is set as 'qa' and tests run fine:
`15:11:33.703 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: qa`.
But when the same command is run with `mvn gatling:test` the env is not set - `15:17:02.980 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: null`

Comment: all that is fine. I need a surefire way to replicate and advise, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across previous post where its suggested to not use -DargLine when specifying arguments - [I want to pass multiple arguments in karate-config.js through mvn command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54229825/i-want-to-pass-multiple-arguments-in-karate-config-js-through-mvn-command?rq=1)

Just pass the command line arguments like:

`mvn gatling:test -DauthUser=*** -DauthPassword=*** -Dkarate.env=qa`